# Python GTK ComboBox - How do clear the dialog when last item is removed

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, gtk

I'm using the following to delete a ComboBox item using Ctrl-X.  This almost works but when the last entry is removed it remains visible until I issue an additional Ctrl-X.

```
 def on_key(self, widget, event, combo):
    if event.state & Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK and event.keyval == 120:
        tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if tree_iter is None:
            combo.grab_focus()
            self.hist_store.append([0, ""])
            self.hist_combo.set_active(0)
            return
        else:
            self.hist_store.remove(tree_iter)
            self.hist_combo.set_active(0)
            return
```